# Eclipse Luna wont give me the option to make a plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a basic app with separate views for a business my buddy is starting with menus such as "our goal" and "contact us" with basic information in them. I have little to no programming skills and everything i find says i need to create a plugin but it doesnt give me the option to make one. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: So, you want a java desktop application? Wouldn't a web page be better to promote a business? Why would you need to create a plugin if you don't have an application that consumes the plugin? Also, eclipse plugins are plugins for eclipse not for applications.

Comment: No I want a phone application and everywhere i look that says how to create a menu that, when clicked, opens a text box, says i need to make a plugin for it. All i want to do is be able to tap one of the buttons in the app on my phone and have it display words but like i stated, i have very little programming experience and cant afford school for it right now

Comment: Since you're using Eclipse and want to create a Java phone app, I'm going to assume that you mean Android. I guess what you need is a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). You could search on [github](https://github.com/) for a basic app skeleton, but will still need to set it up. StackOverflow is not a code writing service, so this question is not **on-topic** here. If can't do it yourself, hire a developer.

Answer (score -1):

you may either want to download the RCP version
[here is the link to the version for RCP developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/lunar)

Comment: How does this link help?

Comment: The version you downloaded seems to be classic version. The RCP version of eclipse will give you the ability to create plugins.